# error while catching an image from an URL

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to catch an image from a URL in my localhost, but somehow it gives an error

```
    import UIKit

let path = "http://localhost/Twitter/Post/52/POST-BCFE0D62-CE3F-407B-B510-CC3B9A8372CF.jpeg"

let url = URL(string: path)!

do {
    let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
} catch {
    print("error \(error)")
}
```

here is the result in my playground. what went wrong in here :(

[image]

error message :

> error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file
>   “POST-BCFE0D62-CE3F-407B-B510-CC3B9A8372CF.jpeg” couldn’t be opened."
>   UserInfo={NSURL=http://localhost/Twitter/Post/52/POST-BCFE0D62-CE3F-407B-B510-CC3B9A8372CF.jpeg}

Comment: please update print("error") line to print("error \(error)")

Comment: @DevanshuSaini Thank you very much,  i have changes

Comment: Use URLSession Data task to solve this issue

Comment: OR try with  different NSData.ReadingOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let url = URL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg")
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let imageData = data {
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

Use above code for getting image from url.Hope it will help you.